# Where does a blank theme inherit its templates from?

Tags: 7, theming

I just enabled my theme only containing an `MYTHEME.info` file. Now I have one query here.

As a output I got broken page. I have checked source of this page. I got some HTML structure.

As per my knowledge, theme renders from `html.tpl.php`. But my theme doesn't contain this file. So from where did it get its HTML structure?

From any core theme/themes?

I have also disabled all previously enabled themes except for the admin theme.

Answer (score 2):

> So from where it got html structure.

It comes from either your theme's base theme, or [the default HTML template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7.x) file included in the system module.

Comment: Hi Clive , I have just tested it.  observed rendering started from   modules/system/html.tpl.php